# Linux Qt QDesktopServices::storageLocation

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, ubuntu-14.04

I am using

```
QtGui.QDesktopServices.storageLocation(QtGui.QDesktopServices.DataLocation)
```

for my cross platform program to get the application folder. On Windows this works well but on Linux (Ubuntu) the current file name is append to the path, e.g.

```
/home/mustermann/.local/share/data//my_program.py
```

I am just wondering whether this is the "normal" behavior and I have to extract the path or something went wrong.

**Edit, code after setting the app name and organisation:**

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setOrganizationName("Snowformtics")
app.setOrganizationDomain("Snowformtics.net")     
app.setApplicationName("LabtoolsQt")     
QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create("plastique"))
QtGui.QApplication.setPalette(QtGui.QApplication.style().standardPalette())
my_app = MyMainWindow()
my_app.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [QStandardPaths::writableLocation()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#writableLocation) and try setting organization and app name.

C++ version:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
app.setOrganizationName("Company Corp.");
app.setOrganizationDomain("company.net");
app.setApplicationName("FancyApp");

qDebug() << QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DataLocation);
```

prints

```
"/home/me/.local/share/Company Corp./FancyApp"
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you create your main application and set the  values?

Comment: [QDesktopServices.storageLocation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdesktopservices-compat.html#storageLocation) is deprecated. Use [QStandardPaths::writableLocation()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#writableLocation)